# plotting 3d with akima: z scale is not in accordance with real data

Tags: r

I have a matrix with 3 columns. I want to make a 3d plot to see the relation between these 3 parameters.

I used akima package in R

```
library(fields)
library(akima)
library(lattice)

data <- read.table("data.txt", header=F)
colnames(data) <- c("A","B","C")  ###A would be x,  B:y and C:z
reggrid <- interp(data$A,data$B,data$C,linear=T,extrap=F,duplicate="mean")
par(family="arial", cex=1.2)
x.ticks <- round(reggrid$x[seq(1,length(reggrid$x),length=5)],5)
y.ticks <- round(reggrid$y[seq(1,length(reggrid$y),length=5)],5)

wireframe(  reggrid$z, 
        xlab=list("A",rot=-30),
        ylab=list("B",rot=35),
        zlab=list("C",rot=0),zlim=c(0,1),
        scales=list(x=list(labels=x.ticks),
                y=list(labels=y.ticks),arrows=F),
        col.regions=rainbow(1000),
        drape=T,
        #shade=T,
        colorkey=T,
 screen=list(z=-20, x=-60, y=0))
```

the problem is that, while the real range of C is between 0-1, in the figures it is between 0.5-0.6!

Would you please help me how to solve this issue?

Comment: Without data, it is complicated.

Comment: How can I add data/attach data?

Comment: You can paste a data sample into your question. For example, to provide the first 10 rows of your data, paste into your question the output of `dput(data[1:10,])`. But you should provide whatever sample of your data is sufficient to illustrate your problem.